# How to pass data from controller to view in Laravel

Tags: laravel, view, controller, laravel-8

Please help me. I have these 3 tables, and I have problems on how to call the `category name` based on the `restaurant id` from `Controller` to `view`. Thank you in advance.

Table `items`

[image]

Table `categories`

[image]

Table `restorant`

[image]

This is my `Controller`

```
public function index()
{

    if (auth()->user()->hasRole('owner')) {
        $items = Items::with('category')->get();
        $restorant_id = auth()->user()->restorant->id;
        $category = Categories::where(['restorant_id' => $restorant_id]);
    }

    return view('point-of-sale::index', [
        'category' => $category,
        'items' => $items,
    ]);
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you add [`get()`](https://laravel.com/api/8.x/Illuminate/Database/Eloquent/Builder.html#method_get) to the end of your `$category = Categories::where(['restorant_id' => $restorant_id]);` statement, you'll have an Eloquent collection returned:

```php
$category = Categories::where(['restorant_id' => $restorant_id])->get();
```

Pass the `$category` variable to your view as you are currently, consider renaming it to `$categories` though just to infer that there could be multiple.

Then in your `view` you can loop over the `Category` results and access the `name` property:

```html
@forelse ($category as $cat)
  {{ $cat->name }}
@empty
  No categories.
@endforelse
```

**Update**

If you want to get `items` by their `category_id`, you can either do as you have done with `$categories`:

```php
$items = Items::where(['category_id' => $category_id])->get();
```

Alternatively, if you have an `items` relationship on your `Categories` model you can access them that way:

```php
$category = Categories::with('items')
    ->where(['restorant_id' => $restorant_id])
    ->get();
```

The above will eager load the `items` related to a `category` which you can then access in your view, for example:

```html
@forelse ($category as $cat)
  {{ $cat->name }}

  @foreach ($cat->items as $item)
    {{ $item->name }}
  @endforeach

@empty
  No categories.
@endforelse
```

Comment: Thank you for your help! May I know, do I need to use the same method to call `Items` based on `category_id`?

Comment: @cdogol I've added a couple examples to the answer for how you might access `items` related to `categories`.

Comment: Why do I get this error? `Property [items] does not exist on this collection instance.`

Comment: @cdogol I have made an assumption that you have a relationship on your `Categories` model called `items`. If that relationship does not exist, you'll get an error, check the [`eloquent relationships`](https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/eloquent-relationships#one-to-many) docs for more info,

Comment: I have, `return $this->hasMany(\App\Items::class, 'category_id', 'id');`

Comment: What is the function names though. That is what Laravel uses when referencing the relationship.

Comment: Hey, your code works yesterday! Sorry, my bad. Thank you again :)